# EventListeners don't function proparly because javascript returns [object HTMLElement]

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add class to a section on mouseover and remove it when mouseout. However, eventlistnere only work on one section, and for the rest, it returns <[object HTMLElement]>.

your help is much appreciated

```
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
let list = document.getElementById("navbar__list");

// this function changes the background of the section to show it is the active one
const activeSection = section => {
 console.log(`here ${section}`);
 section.className = "your-active-class";
};

// this function return the section to its normal status when the user is not viewing it anymore
const inactiveSection = section => {
 console.log(`there ${section.id}`);
 section.className = "";
};
for (section of sections) {
 section.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
   activeSection(section);
 });
 section.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
   inactiveSection(section);
 });
 let point = document.createElement("li");
 let link = document.createElement("a");
 link.className = "menu__link";
 link.textContent = section.id;
 link.href = `#${section.id}`;
 point.appendChild(link);
 list.appendChild(point);
}
```

Comment: You should be using css styling to do that.  Have a look at [css pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) - particularly, `:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To see `[object HTMLElement]` in the console is absolutly normal. When you call

```
console.log(`here ${section}`)
```

`section` can't be converted to a sting so it is replace by `[object HTMLElement]`.

2. Now, you'r script isn't working for another reason. When you write

```
for (section of sections) {
```

you create a global variable `section` which is overwriten at every iteration. The last iteration being your last `<section>` element. When the listener callback function is called this is always the same `<section>` which is passed as argument.

To fix that you need to scope the `section` variable to the for loop block, like so

```
for (let section of sections) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that I missed the let.